# Does Direct3D Feature Level guarantee non-power-of-2 support for volume textures?

Tags: direct3d

In Direct3D9 there were [capability flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9caps/ns-d3d9caps-d3dcaps9) like :

> - `D3DPTEXTURECAPS_NONPOW2CONDITIONAL`: ... conditionally supports the use of 2D textures with dimensions that are not powers of two ...
> - `D3DPTEXTURECAPS_POW2`: ... all textures must have widths and heights specified as powers of two. This requirement does not apply to ... volume textures ...
> - `D3DPTEXTURECAPS_VOLUMEMAP_POW2`: Device requires that volume texture maps have dimensions specified as powers of two.

In Direct3D10 there are [feature levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro) instead.
Feature level `10_0` and above have:

> - Nonpowers-of-2 unconditionally⁴
>
> ⁴ At feature levels 10_0, 10_1 and 11_0, the display device unconditionally supports the use of 2-D textures with dimensions that are not powers of two.

But 3-D textures are not mentioned.

Are there any guarantees about support for non-power-of-2 volume textures in D3D10+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct3D 10 and later defined all resource sizes to have no specific restrictions for power-of-2 sizing, or filtering functionality associated with them.

> While they are not super easy to understand, you can look at the engineering specs for Direct3D 11 on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Specs)